# Using variables in Asp.NET Control Attributes in Html View

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wonder if there is any way to do this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSomething" runat="server" Visible="this.ShowLabel"/>
```

and in the code behind:

```
public bool ShowLabel {get;set;}
```

I know some of you may ask me why I need it but I find this approach cleaner than saying this in the code behind:

```
lblSomething.Visible = this.ShowLabel
```

And also I could say this in source view:

```
<% if(this.ShowLabel){ %>
   <asp:Label ID="lblSomething" runat="server" Text="Something"/>
<% } %>
```

but again, the first one would be more intuitive to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly in your case, the easiest, cleanest and most elegant solution **is using `Visible` attribute, instead of creating other boolean and make `Visible` have the same value**.

In the other hand, `Label` control isn't a sealed class. If you need to do such things, I'd find better derive `Label` and implement `ShowLabel` property this way:

```
private bool _showLabel;

public bool ShowLabel
{
    get { return _showLabel; }
    set
    {
        _showLabel = value;
        Visible = value
    }
}
```

Finally, your new `MyLabel` control usage would be:

```
<gray:MyLabel ID="lblSomething" runat="server" ShowLabel="true"/>
```

Anyway, and again, if you're hidding such control using `Visible`, don't reinvent the wheel: use what comes from ASP.NET. However, if your question shows a sample but real-world scenario isn't `Visible` but other things, I'd argue that you should use inheritance (this is more elegant than your proposal).

In fact, a good ASP.NET Web Forms practice is completely separate markup from presentation logic.

Answer (score 2):

If your `ShowLabel` property is really just a wrapper around the visibility property of the label, you can just replace your property definition with:

```
public bool ShowLabel
{
    get { return lblSomething.Visible; }
    set { lblSomething.Visible = value; }
}
```

But that doesn't really give you much other than a new name for the visibility property.